# How to read from properties file?

Tags: java, file, properties

I want to read a line from properties file called jdbc.properties. It locate in `src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\db\jdbc.properties`. What path should I use?
This is my method:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();

        try {
            // load a properties file
            prop.load(new FileInputStream("jdbc.properties"));

            System.out.println(prop.getProperty("password"));

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Put the properties file inside `src/main/resources` and access it with a classloader.

Comment: But I thought that everybody could see my data if it not in webinf. There is my password.

Comment: When your source is compiled, classes files and everything in `src/main/resources` will be put in `WEB-INF/classes` so no worries.

Comment: Done. And so what should I do with my code? What path?

Comment: See my answer below. Same-ish code, just change how you get the `InputStream` to that properties resource.

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: `prop.load(Provider.class.getResourceAsStream("backup.properties"));

      System.out.println(prop.getProperty("backup.password"));`

Comment: In backup.properties `jdbc.password=7f4df454`

Comment: You must have missed my update. You need to provide a leading `/` to the String path. So `prop.load(Provider.class.getResourceAsStream("/backup.properties"));`

Comment: If you don't put the leading `/`, the classloader looks for the resource in whatever package the `Provider` class is in, not at the root as it should.

Comment: Thank you. I selected your answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you move your properties file to `src/main/resources`, assuming your project is managed by maven, then you could retrieve it by doing

```
Properties prop = new Properties();

try {
    // load a properties file
    prop.load(YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/jdbc.properties")); // note the leading /

    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("password"));

} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

where `YourClass` is whatever class this code is in.

Maven places the class files of your compiled classes and all resources in `src/main/resources` in `WEB-INF/classes` where only your application can access them.

If you put the file in `src/main/resources/someFolder`, you'll need to access it from

```
prop.load(YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/someFolder/jdbcProperties"));
```

The path you provide to the above method is relative to the package of the class you are in, unless you specify a leading forward-slash, in which case it will be relative to the root of the classpath, ie `classes` folder.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify an absolute path to the `FileInputStream`. You can get the path by calling `servletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/db/jdbc.properties")`

If you do not have the `servletContext` available (via `.getServletContext()`), then you should pass it (or the absolute path to the root of the app) to the code above.

Comment: I added a 2nd paragraph. I don't know where your code resides, so I assumed it's in a servlet

Comment: Use Class.getResourceAsStream

Answer (score 0):

Is environment variable set for TOMCAT_HOME, if not set it up.

Now you can use

`<tomcat_home>/webapps/<yourapp>/web-inf/db/jdbc.properties`

To get value of environment variable use following code:

```
Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
```

Cheers !!